# Consecutive months and gaps in SQL to get max consecutive months and max gaps month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having a roadblock on dataset I am trying to create. I am looking to find the consecutive months of Invoicing for clients.
If there is break in months the count should restart. My end dataset would provide me the max consecutive months, max or total gaps in months.

Here is sample table:

```
select 'Demo Client' as ClientName,'1' as InvoiceMonthNumber,'20201' InvoiceYearMonth,'2020' InvoiceYear
into #tempa
union select 'Demo Client','2','20202','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','3','20203','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','4','20204','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','5','20205','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','6','20206','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','7','20207','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','10','202010','2020'
union select 'Demo Client','5','20215','2021'
union select 'Demo Client','6','20216','2021'
union select 'Demo Client','7','20217','2021'
union select 'Demo Client','8','20218','2021'
union select 'Demo Client','9','20219','2021'
union select 'Demo Client','10','202110','2021'


select * 
from #tempa
where invoiceyear = 2020

select * 
from #tempa
where invoiceyear = 2021
```

Here, For this client, The max no. of consecutive months of invoice would be 7 for year 2020.
The gaps in months is:
month 8,9 in 2020
month 11,12 of 2020
month 1,2,3,4,5 of 2021
so max gap would be of 5 months

I am looking for ideas and logic.

Comment: can you add a desired result for clarification ?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the difference between the current and the next month.

Something like this :

```
SELECT ClientName
    ,InvoiceYear
    ,COUNT(1) + 1 AS NumberOfConsecutiveMonths
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,lead(InvoiceYearMonth) OVER (
           PARTITION BY invoiceYear ORDER BY CAST(InvoiceYearMonth AS INT)
          ) - CAST(InvoiceYearMonth AS INT) AS diff
    FROM #tempa
) a
WHERE difF = 1
GROUP BY ClientName
      ,InvoiceYear
```